# Soap Webservice client sends empty http request while connecting

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I implemented a jax-ws soap webservice and generated sources with wsimport.
This is what I do to establish the connection:

```
outMessagePort = new OutMessage(wsdlUrl).getOutMessageHttpSoap11Endpoint()
```

When calling this line, I could see in the network trace, that two requests were sent:

```
10.11.12.1 - - [18/Sep/2018:19:03:03 +0200] "GET /anyWS/services/OutMessage HTTP/1.1" 500 171 0.003 3
10.11.12.1 - - [18/Sep/2018:19:03:03 +0200] "GET /anyWS/services/OutMessage?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 4382 0.010 10
```

The response for the first request was a 500 error.
Does anybody know why the webservice sends this message? Is it possible to prevent java from sending it?

Comment: Did you check if the webservice is working fine? 500 usually means something is wrong at the server end...

Comment: The webservice is working as far as I can see. Posting messages works fine. Only the one request at the beginning of the connection is a problem.